# Can the type parameter be a reference in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I need a method like the following:

```
methodA(Class<? extends ClassA> clzz, Consumer<? extends ClassA> consumer) {
   //... AKKA message handler
   .match(clzz, s -> consumer.accept(s);)
}
```

This won't compile and I know why, what I want is something like:

```
TypeParameter T = ? extends ClassA;
methodA(Class<T> clzz, Consumer<T> consumer){//...}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A type is a type, not a value. This is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<T extends ClassA> methodA(Class<T> clzz, Consumer<T> consumer) {
   //... AKKA message handler
   .match(clzz, s -> consumer.accept(s);)
}
```

(Note that you can make it more flexible using `Consumer<? super T>`)

Comment: Could you explain why this isn't what is being asked for?

Comment: Thanks! Don't know where the down vote came from, your suggestion actually works. Haven't thought of this solution before as this situation exists in several places of my code, in some other classes I need to assign the ```clzz``` and ```consumer``` arguments to the class properties,  so I have to make the class a generic class if doing so, these classes are AKKA message classes, my previous concern is that the message matching ```.match(MessageA.class, s->{…})``` will not work having a generic message class like ```MessageA<T extends A> ```. @AndyTurner

Comment: @Yulin that's a fundamental limitation of an API designed to match on classes.